# Cppyy cmake build unable to find LibClang

Tags: c++, cmake, cppyy

I've been trying to use cppyy to build some python bindings for a C++ library. At the moment I am using the cookiecutter recipe from here: https://github.com/camillescott/cookiecutter-cppyy-cmake

But the package is having trouble finding `LibClang_LIBRARY` and `LibClang_PYTHON_EXECUTABLE`. This is the same case if I install cppyy with conda or pip, and importing cppyy in python works fine.

I have tried manually defining the paths with `cmake -DLibClang_LIBRARY=<path/to/libclang> -DLibClang_PYTHON_EXECUTABLE=<path/to/executable> ..` and although it then finds `LibClang_LIBRARY`, it is unable to find `LibClang_PYTHON_EXECUTABLE`.

It appears to be a problem with cmake finding the appropriate paths, the full error is

```
CMake Error at /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.21.3/share/cmake/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:230 (message):
  Could NOT find LibClang (missing: LibClang_LIBRARY
  LibClang_PYTHON_EXECUTABLE)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.21.3/share/cmake/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:594 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  cmake/FindLibClang.cmake:47 (FIND_PACKAGE_HANDLE_STANDARD_ARGS)
  cmake/FindCppyy.cmake:286 (find_package)
  CMakeLists.txt:71 (cppyy_add_bindings)
```

Has anyone else found this problem or even better a solution to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cmake fragments in the cookie cutter example seem to be older than the ones in cppyy-cling: https://github.com/wlav/cppyy-backend/tree/master/cling/python/cppyy_backend/cmake

(These are the ones installed under `cppyy_backend/cmake` in the Python `site-packages` directory.)

The newer version protects the searches with a predicate in case the variables are explicitly defined as you do with the `-D...` option, which I suspect will then solve most of the issues you encountered.

It also uses `llvm-config` if available, which is more robust than trying likely directories.

Comment: Thanks, by removing the coockiecutter files and using the installed make files this error disappears!