# Cppyy cmake build cannot find libclang

Tags: c++, cmake, llvm, libclang, cppyy

I am trying to build cppyy via cmake but I keep getting this error:

```
CPYY_MODULE_PATH: /usr/local/anaconda3/envs/bwcpp_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/cppyy_backend/cmake
CMake Error at /usr/local/anaconda3/envs/bwcpp_env/share/cmake-3.25/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:230 (message):
  Could NOT find LibClang (missing: LibClang_PYTHON_EXECUTABLE) (found
  version "/usr/local/anaconda3/envs/bwcpp_env/lib/libclang.dylib")
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/local/anaconda3/envs/bwcpp_env/share/cmake-3.25/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:600 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  /usr/local/anaconda3/envs/bwcpp_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/cppyy_backend/cmake/FindLibClang.cmake:77 (FIND_PACKAGE_HANDLE_STANDARD_ARGS)
  CMakeLists.txt:99 (find_package)
```

The comment here: [Cppyy cmake build unable to find LibClang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69363344/cppyy-cmake-build-unable-to-find-libclang)
implies that using the linked `findLibClang.cmake` file fixes the issue but I checked my file located here: `/usr/local/anaconda3/envs/bwcpp_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/cppyy_backend/cmake/FindLibClang.cmake` and found that they were identical and the issue is still there.

I have also tried running with and without these flags but I keep getting the same error

```
-DLibClang_PYTHON_EXECUTABLE=/usr/local/anaconda3/envs/bwcpp_env/bin/python
-DLibClang_LIBRARY=/usr/local/anaconda3/envs/bwcpp_env/lib/libclang.dylib
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I was actually just missing the `python-clang` package. I installed that with `conda install -c conda-forge python-clang` and the problem was fixed.